# Capture try catch exceptions in wcf trace

Tags: asp.net, wcf, exception, trace

I implemented WCF trace with this code:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="CardSpace" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IO.Log" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.IdentityModel" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\wcflogs\trace.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="Default" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="500" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="5000" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

but it trace only exeptions that are thrown outside the try/catch block, so when I want to have this exception in my trace I need to remove try/catch block. Is there any way to have this exception from try {} also in my WCF trace?

Comment: I don't think so, because your code is handling the exception (via the try/catch block).  If you want to capture the exceptions inside a try/catch block, log them to a file or a database inside the `catch`.

Comment: Yeah I'm catching exceptions and loging them to db but maybe is there also any way to have it also in my trace file

Answer (score 0):

Just add another source to your config file.  You should still able to use a shared listener.  I think.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
   <source name="HandledExceptions" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
     <add initializeData="HandledExceptions.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="HandledExceptionListener">
      <filter type="" />
     </add>
    </listeners>
   </source>
  </sources>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
 </system.diagnostics>
```

And then write an event in code

```
catch (FaultException fe)
{
    TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("HandledExceptions");
    trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 0, fe.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + fe.StackTrace);
    trace.Flush();
    trace.Close();

    throw fe;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("HandledExceptions");
    trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical, 0, e.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
    trace.Flush();
    trace.Close();

    throw new FaultException(e.Message);
}
```